# Create flag column after comparing two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have two different report tables with datetimes and the report owner. I would like to select the people who have written either reports at least once. I also need a calculated field that shows which report number they wrote. Report 1 takes precedence, so if at any time someone authored report one, the new report_number column should say 1, else 2 (for report 2).

```
'people' table
| person_id | full_name
--------------------------
| 1         | John L Smith
| 2         | Carl M Selt
| 3         | Another Person

'report_1' table
| report_1_id | author_person_id | date_entered | other_columns
---------------------------------------------------------------
| 1           | 1                | 2018-01-12   | foo
| 2           | 1                | 2018-02-18   | foo foo

'report_2' table
| report_2_id | author_person_id | date_entered | other_columns
---------------------------------------------------------------
| 1           | 1                | 2018-03-21   | bar
| 2           | 1                | 2018-03-28   | bar bar
| 3           | 2                | 2018-04-16   | baz
| 4           | 2                | 2018-04-30   | baz baz
```

**Desired results:**

```
| full_name    | report_number
---------------------------
| John L Smith | 1
| Carl M Smelt | 2
```

Note that John's `report_number` is `1` even though he also authored a report 2.

Report 1 and report 2 have different additional columns even though they look the same above.

**What I tried:**

```
    /* Get people from both reports */
WITH report_1_people AS (
    SELECT P.full_name
    FROM report_1 R1
    INNER JOIN people P ON R1.author_person_id = P.person_id
    WHERE P.full_name IS NOT NULL 
    AND P.full_name <> ''
), report_2_people AS (
    SELECT P2.full_name
    FROM report_2 R2
    INNER JOIN people P2 ON R2.author_person_id = P2.person_id
    WHERE P2.full_name IS NOT NULL 
    AND P2.full_name <> ''
)
SELECT 
    P.full_name,
    CASE WHEN P.full_name IN ( /* Check if in report 1 */
                    SELECT full_name
                    FROM report_1)
                    THEN 1
            ELSE 2
            END AS report_number
FROM people P
WHERE P.full_name IS NOT NULL AND P.full_name <> ''
/* Eliminate duplicate names */
GROUP BY P.full_name 
/* Filter only who either authored report 1 or report 2 */
HAVING P.full_name IN (SELECT full_name
                       FROM report_1_people)
OR P.full_name IN (SELECT full_name
                   FROM report_2_people)
```

*Note: There is a `GROUP BY` with the people table because for some reason there are duplicates entries.*

Query took so long it disconnected from the database (24+ hours), so I think I'm doing something wrong. Is there a better way to accomplish this flag calculated column based on two tables? Relatively new to SQL so I'm wondering if there is another way of thinking I am over looking with SQL logic.

Comment: In the CTE queries, use the `person_id` instead. Then in your `Select LEFT JOIN` the 2 `CTE` tables to the `people` table. Remove the `Group By` and `Having`... Remove the `Case` statement and replace that with an `ISNULL(CTE1, CTE2)` for the `ReportID` See what you get then.

Comment: The having clause with checks on `P.full_name`, weird as you are already grouping on `P.full_name`. Move the checks to the where clause. Then, having the OR to check if they are in two tables, can be rewritten as checking IN with a UNION of the two queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IN`s on the CTEs are likely to kill it dead.

An alternative way is to use `EXISTS` to check if a person has written a report. A `CASE` expression can handle the precedence.

```
SELECT p.full_name,
       CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                             FROM report_1 r1
                             WHERE r1.author_person_id = p.person_id) THEN
           1
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                             FROM report_2 r2
                             WHERE r2.author_person_id = p.person_id) THEN
           2
       END report_number
       FROM people p
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM report_1 r1
                            WHERE r1.author_person_id = p.person_id)
              OR EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM report_2 r2
                                WHERE r2.author_person_id = p.person_id);
```

For performance try indexes on `report_1 (author_person_id)` and `report_2 (author_person_id)`. For `people` you might experiment with an index on `person_id`(which likely already exists) or maybe a compound one on `person_id` and `full_name`.

Comment: This is great! I didn't consider this approach because I thought a correlated subquery would be slower. This approach seems to be the fastest of the suggested solutions. I removed the second EXIST check in the case statement since 2 in the bottom where clause ensures they are either report 1 or report 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT person_id, full_name, COALESCE(ca1.report_num, ca2.report_num)
FROM people
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) 1 FROM report_1 WHERE author_person_id = people.person_id) AS ca1(report_num)
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) 2 FROM report_2 WHERE author_person_id = people.person_id) AS ca2(report_num)
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0194f79481cab4426115f061550fd5f9)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This returns lots NULL values in the new column though since it's doing doing OUTER APPLY (which I believe is like LEFT JOIN). I haven't heard of APPLY though so I'll research to see if this is function I should use more often.

Answer (score 0):

This is just another way of getting the result.

```
SELECT 
    P.full_name,
    MIN( R.Report_Number) AS report_number
FROM people P
OUTER APPLY (SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM report_1 R1 WHERE R1.author_person_id = P.person_id)
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 2 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM report_2 R2 WHERE R2.author_person_id = P.person_id)) AS R(Report_Number)
WHERE P.full_name IS NOT NULL AND P.full_name <> ''
/* Eliminate duplicate names */
GROUP BY P.full_name;
```